# resource items total count calculation (separate query vs collection)

Tags: php, performance, mongodb, domain-driven-design, transformation

im struggling with finding the best way to get total items of items when returning a resource collection im thinking of two approaches just want your opinion regarding whats best ?

scenario :

a user want to retrieve list of `10` vehicles from my `10000` vehicles with some cursors such as (limit, before, after, filters, etc ...)

option 1:

```
class VehiclesRepo()
{
    function getVehicles(){
        // get 10000 vehicles with one query; : returns collection
        // return 10000 vehicles and do filtration on transformation layer to keep total_count of vehicles 
    }
}
```

option 2:

```
class VehiclesRepo()
{
    function getVehicles(){
        // get 10 vehicles with one query including filtration; : returns collection
        // return 10 vehicles, and do another query for total_count
    }
}
```

please consider operation effect on memory, cpu circles ? also my system is fully ddd so im trying not to have a domain leaks

Comment: What is the question? Are you talking about *"this query matched 10 results out of a possible 10000"* to be entered into your response? Not very clear here.

Comment: exactly @BlakesSeven im trying to do that without having to access infrastructure layer from outside the domain

Comment: Well here's the great big DDD pfft! and problem. If you want to design class infrastructure that knows nothing of the underlying storage mechanism, then you end up with garbage that just deals in base coding concepts such as *"pull in this great big list of data, count how many things in it, then give me a filtered count and results from that criterion"*. Which is of course all well and fine for small arrays, but falls apart in the real world ( I've seem people try ). If anything, have accessors for "total count" and "query" where you tie those to "smart" methods underneath. Two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are basically ok, but I think with 10'000 vehicles you have already a performance problem if you use option 1. So I'd go with option 2.

But there is probably another problem with your design:

> I'm trying to do that without having to access infrastructure layer from outside the domain.

This comment suggests that you have the following layering:

```
 Application
      ⇣
   Domain
      ⇣
Infrastructure
```

If you don't use some kind of the [Dependency Inversion Priciple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) that actually makes the infrastructure dependent on the domain layer, then you have a problem with this design. The domain should be as pure as possible. If the domain has a dependency on the infrastructure, this means that you cannot use your domain model independently of the infrastructure. This is bad, because the infrastructure is an artificial thing that does not exist in the real world of your domain.

So what you should do conceptually is this:

```
Application
   ⇣     ⇣
   ⇣    Infrastructure
   ⇣    ⇣
   Domain
```

Then your repository implementations become natural and allow query operations like e.g.:

- Give me Vehicle with ID X
- Give me all Vehicles with more than Y wheels
- Give me all Vehicles that match the filter Z

Note that these query operations should return actual business objects, not DTOs or database rows or alike.

If you want to read more about pros and cons of different architectures with DDD, I suggest you read the chapter "Architecture" in *Implementing DDD* by Vaughn Vernon.

---

Note on @plaxl's answer: The answer is specific to CQRS, which you don't mention in your question with a single word. So outside of a CQRS context, using the domain model for query operations is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

> im trying to do that without having to access infrastructure layer
>   from outside the domain

That's actually your problem. DDD aggregates are designed around command processing, transactional consistency and business invariants, not querying needs.

That's why CQRS is so popular these days. I would strongly advise you not to rely on your domain model for query needs.

Comment: The OP doesn't ask about CQRS, so I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @theDmi CQRS is nothing magical. It just means segregating queries from commands. You do not need a framework, a separate data store or have asynchronous commands. When going through the domain model for queries, you will face the SELECT n+1 problem at some point and things will just get worse and worse. Not only that, but sharing a single model favors large aggregates with the use of lazy loading which is also considered an anti-pattern these days.

Comment: I know it's nothing magical, but it's not the silver bullet either. But this isn't even the topic here, I was just stating that the question is not about CQRS. Whether or not CQRS is a good architectural style for the OP's project is IMHO impossible to say from the question alone.